# Unnecessary Horizontal Scroll on Grid WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox

I have a grid inside a list box. And one of the columns of the grid has width *. and other columns have static width.The horizontal scroll bar for the list view always appears even when the space is more than enough. I want the scroll bar to appear only when needed i.e. the space is not enough.

What is going on here how do i fix it.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
                 Margin="0"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Padding="0"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 AutomationProperties.Name="MyListBox"
                 AutomationProperties.AutomationId="MyListBox"
                 Name="MyListBox" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">


                 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Width>
                        <Binding ElementName="MyListBox" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                    </Grid.Width>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ShCol" width="25"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition width ="30">
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding `Grid.Width` to `ListBox.ActualWidth`, set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```